# Cannot get minimum value from Array (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the minimum value from an Array, and i come across this weird behavior. 
My expectation is to get 89 as the minimumDistance, instead i get 100.
Can anyone explain this ?

```
// List 

var nodes = {
    "node": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "id": "2",
        "edges": {
          "edge": [
            {
              "to": "4",
              "distance": "89"
            },
            {
              "to": "6",
              "distance": "100"
            },
            {
              "to": "8",
              "distance": "500"
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
}

// Initialization
startNode = 0
currentNode = startNode;


edge = nodes.node[currentNode].edges.edge;
var minimumDistance = 99999;

// Loop through the Neighbors of one Node
for (x= 0; x<edge.length; x++) {
  if (edge[x].distance < minimumDistance) {
      minimumDistance = edge[x].distance;
      } 
  document.write('Neighbor: ' + edge[x].to + ', Distance: ' + edge[x].distance);
  document.write('</br>');
}
 document.write('</br>');
document.write('Minimum Distance: ' + minimumDistance );
```

Comment: Is there some other reason you are storing these numeric properties as strings rather than numbers? The cause of the problem is that you're sorting strings, not numbers - you could fix it by altering the line that does the comparison, but you'll likely cause yourself fewer headaches by just changing the data to use numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond No particular reason, the array is actually json and much bigger in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a number instead of a string for comparing. Comparing string is different from numbers.
Here is some example:

```js
var nodes = { node: [{ name: "test", id: "2", edges: { edge: [{ to: "4", distance: "89" }, { to: "6", distance: "100" }, { to: "8", distance: "500" }] } }] },
    startNode = 0,
    currentNode = startNode,
    edge = nodes.node[currentNode].edges.edge,
    minimumDistance = Infinity, // greatest value
    x;

for (x = 0; x < edge.length; x++) {
    if (+edge[x].distance < minimumDistance) { // unary plus for getting a number
        minimumDistance = edge[x].distance;
    } 
    document.write('Neighbor: ' + edge[x].to + ', Distance: ' + edge[x].distance);
    document.write('</br>');
}
document.write('</br>');
document.write('Minimum Distance: ' + minimumDistance );
```

Comment: didn't know +would change a string tto a number. great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down to a minimum code example. You are looking for the minimum value of the property `distance` within the `edge` array within your (imho overly nested) `nodes` object.

Problem is that the `distance` values are strings, not numbers. So, the values should be converted to `Number` to be able to compare them and determine the minimum of the `distance` values. Now the distances are mapped to `Number` by using `+[a numeric string value]`.

To determine the minimum value you can subsequently apply `Math.min` to the mapped array of numeric values.

```js
const edge =  [
      {
        "to": "4",
        "distance": "89"
      },
      {
        "to": "6",
        "distance": "100"
      },
      {
        "to": "8",
        "distance": "500"
      }
];
// map distances to numeric values
const distancesFromEdge = edge.map( val => +val.distance );
// determine the minimum value of the mapped values
const minDistance = Math.min.apply(null, distancesFromEdge);
console.log(minDistance);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Robin pointed out - you're comparing strings. If you can't store integers in your data source, you can do the following with `parseInt()`;

```
if (parseInt(edge[x].distance) < minimumDistance) {
      minimumDistance = parseInt(edge[x].distance);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the strings to numbers in distance object.

```js
var nodes = {
    "node": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "id": "2",
        "edges": {
          "edge": [
            {
              "to": "4",
              "distance": 89
            },
            {
              "to": "6",
              "distance": 100
            },
            {
              "to": "8",
              "distance": 500
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
}
```